# `last` alternative showing logins only for current user

Tags: shell-script, scripting, freebsd, last

I'm aware that I can use `last $USER`, however this won't work correctly or securely on machines with many users - no user should know another users IP or when they logged in. Is there a known solution for this problem, or should I atte

Comment: `/var/log/wtmp` is world-readable, so even if you replace `last` with a program that only shows the current user's info, there's nothing stopping another user from installing `last` under their own home dir.  or reading `wtmp` with a perl or python script, or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

On FreeBSD the files you should be aware of are:

```
/var/log/utx.log
/var/log/utx.lastlogin
```

`utmp` was replaced by `utmpx` in 9.0

A common but brute method is to link the file to /dev/null. All data written to the file would then be void.

```
ln -sf /dev/null /var/log/utx.log
```

Or you can remove access to the db for the `lastlog` command:

```
chmod o-r /var/log/utx.lastlog
```

The above have the advantage that you as root still have access to the database - but not the users. That would be my preferred choice.

But if you want the users to have partial access it will become hard. You could create a wrapper script replacing `last` and `lastlogin` which display only the info that you want. But the data is still written to a world readable file so the users could then look at that file instead.

Last you can also choose which ttys you want to enable logging for using [ac](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ac&sektion=8&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.2-RELEASE). You could then choose not to log for all `pts` which usually are your ssh sessions.

But again if security is you concern you probably want to keep logging - but simply remove the world readable file access to the database files.

Answer (score 0):

If your users are logging in via `ssh`, as I would assume, then one way to accomplish this might be to build `sshd` from source yourself, supplying the `--disable-utmp --disable-utmpx --disable-wtmp --disable-wtmpx` flags to `configure`. I haven't tried this, just a suggestion.